# Detect asynchronous calls are finished, then trigger another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred

What is the best way to detect when all of my asynchronous calls are finished then trigger another function?  I have three querys that are triggered by the user picking a topic.  These querys run and their return values are then combined to be used in a new function.  The problem is I need to know when they are all done then run the new function.

```
function queryHandler1() {
    // do something
    return result1;
}

function queryHandler2() {
    // do something
    return result2;
}

function queryHandler3() {
    // do something
    return result3;
}

function alldone(result1, result2, result3) {
     // do something
    return result4;
}
```

I have tried using jquery.when(), but it only runs the first time and when the user picks a new option it does not trigger alldone?

```
// global
var d1 = $.Deferred();
var d2 = $.Deferred();
var d3 = $.Deferred();

function queryHandler1() {
    // do something
    d1.resolve();
    return result1;
}

function queryHandler2() {
    // do something
    d2.resolve();
    return result2;
}

function queryHandler3() {
    // do something
    d3.resolve();
    return result3;
}

function alldone(result1, result2, result3) {
     // do something
    return result4;
}

// the top level $.when
$.when(d1, d2, d3).done(function() {
    alldone();
});
```

How do I reset the deferred or resolve so that all done is triggered again?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user9263373 took a look at that question but it is not for JavaScript so did not help, thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue with what I think is an inelegant solution, but it works.

```
function queryHandler1() {
    // do something
    alldone(); 
}

function queryHandler2() {
    // do something
    alldone();
}

function queryHandler3() {
    // do something
    alldone();
}
var numCalls = 0;
function alldone() {
     if (numCalls === 2) {
          // do something
          console.log("YES ALL DONE");
     } else {
          numCalls ++;
     }
}
```

Any improvements?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Async library](http://caolan.github.io/async/index.html)

For your case you can use [async.parallel](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel) or [async.series](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series)
 depending on wether you want to run your tasks simultaneously or sequentially

To use the library in the browser https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/async